# Bad substitution?

Tags: bash, bash4

I'm having what seems like a pretty simple problem that I can't seem to fix, and the only help I'm getting from bash is that it's a bad substitution. Any help?

```
#!/bin/bash
lang=Python
frameworks=('Python=(Django Flask Pyramid)' 'Ruby=(Rails Cuba)')
for i in "${frameworks[@]}";do eval $i;done
echo "Python ${#$lang[@]} ${$lang[@]}"
echo "Ruby ${#Ruby[@]} ${Ruby[@]}"
```

Line 5 above is what throws the error, but line 6 works perfectly, which should do the same thing?

Output:

```
>>>line 5: Python ${#$lang[@]} ${$lang[@]}: bad substitution
>>>Ruby 2 Rails Cuba
```

Comment: This is [Bash FAQ 006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `$lang` in this way (obviously). The bash array construct `${name[@]}` is a little bit sacred. If you want to deference on `$lang` this way, you'll need another `eval`.

Try this instead:

```
eval "echo \"Python  \${#$lang[@]} \${$lang[@]}\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Use indirection. Assign what you want to expand to a variable, in this case `Python[@]`, and then use `${!thatvariable}`:

```
mything="$lang[@]"
echo "${!mything}"
```